# Removing a gem from GemCutter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemcutter

I want to delete a gem I uploaded to GemCutter. I couldn't find any commands for this. Some time ago there was a [blog post](http://update.gemcutter.org/2009/09/25/kinetic-energy.html) stating gem deletion as an upcoming feature. I haven't seen any further official announcements about this feature.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current way to do this is submit a request on http://help.rubygems.org, and I'll manually remove it. I'm hoping to get gem deletion in the API and in the gemcutter gem by the end of the month.